# CSS Default LI color

Tags: css

I can't get my font color of my menu list items to black. Now they are just blue/purple the hover functions etc works fine..

CSS Code:

```
#menu8 {


    background-color: 7c7b7b;
    width:225px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
}   

 #menu8 li a {

    text-decoration: none;
    voice-family: "\"}\""; 
     voice-family: inherit;
 }

 #menu8 li a:link, #menu8 li a:visited {
    color: #777;
    display: block;
    background: url(images/menu8.gif);
    padding: 8px 0 0 20px;
}

#menu8 li a:hover {
    color: #257EB7;
    background: url(images/menu8.gif) 0 -32px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 25px;
}

 #menu8 li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images/menu8.gif) 0 -64px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 25px;
}

 #menu8 ul {
    list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The headings are black, but the list items not...

Comment: Seems to all work fine. The answer below is irrelevant. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ryxb2/

Comment: That is exactly what I mean, the text behind the bulletpoint needs to be black too.

Comment: #777 isn't black. You have no statements indicating black in your code.

Comment: Here's black: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ryxb2/2/

Comment: My apologies, for this stupid question. I must have overlooked that. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No worries. We've all been there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

the background-color on #menu8 is missing a # in front of the HEX value, #000 is black

```
#menu8 li { color: #000; }/*any text not wrapped in an anchor this would change the color of the discs*/
#menu8 li a { color: #000; } /*any text wrapped in anchor*/
```

Comment: While true, that's not relevant here, near as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for responding but this only makes the <h></h> black the <li></li> stays the same, i need them black to.